# How should I shut down and restart a Swing JFrame thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe

My application's main frame starts a JFrame thread:

```
IBM1622GUI cardReadPunchGUI = new IBM1622GUI(); // instantiate
Thread cardReadPunchThread = new Thread(cardReadPunchGUI); // alloc thread
cardReadPunchThread.start(); // call thread's run() method
```

Later, the main frame needs to "destroy" IBM1622GUI (as part of "taking a peripheral offline"), and still later, to reinstantiate it - presumably using the same procedure as above.  What should the main frame do to basically return to the state prior to when the IBM1622GUI was first instantiated?

EDIT - I should probably mention that IBM1622GUI, the JFrame class, is being developed with NetBeans as a "Swing GUI Form", and thus there are certain limitations on what edits I can make to the source code.

Comment: We don't have enough information on your code.  We know nothing of what the main frame "state" is.

Comment: It's fully operational, visible - just sitting there having its event handlers driven by the EDT.  Is that sufficient info?  I didn't write the main frame - it's 12 years old and uses AWT (no Swing).

Comment: I stupidly thought "main frame" referred to a simulated IBM main frame computer...

Comment: I guess `cardReadPunchGUI.dispose(); cardReadPunchGUI = new IBM1622GUI();` should do what you want.  However it's not clear if some of the "state" of the first cardReadPunchGUI might still be present in some other objects.

Comment: @toto: Hah!  Actually, the entire app *is* a simulation of a very old IBM "mainframe."  But here I'm referring to the first, primary window, which shows the console of an IBM1620.  Turning on the power switch causes the allocation of a faceless "CPU" thread and a 1622 Card Read/Punch unit (a separate JFrame).  Turning *off* the power switch should dispose of those items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Read this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

You should use this style to init a JFrame.

```
IBM1622GUI cardReadPunchGUI = null;
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        cardReadPunchGUI = new IBM1622GUI();
    }
});
```

[When you want to close the JFrame, here is already the question with answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258099/how-to-close-a-java-swing-application-from-the-code)

(Edit by Chap: the linked SO thread is very long and meandering, but it boils down to simply using `cardReadPunchGUI.dispose()`.  This does, in fact, answer my question satisfactorily, and I'd like to give credit for this answer but I would also like for this note to be included.)

Comment: Both of the links that you included appear to deal with "main" threads, and the process of terminating the *application*.  I don't want to quit the Application, but rather close a secondary window and later reopen it.  If that answer is contained in the links, it's not obvious to me :-)

Comment: Its not only for main threads. The 2nd link contains the solution with [dispose](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29) Why you don't use it?

Comment: I believe the `new IBM1622GUI()` is actually started from the "main frame", so it's already in the EDT.

Comment: Edited answer to highlight the fact that dispose() was the answer to my question.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to [`suspend()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#suspend%28%29) and [`resume()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#suspend%28%29) the `cardReadPunchThread`. Although those methods are deprecated, you can use the approach outlined in [*Java Thread Primitive Deprecation*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) as a way to control the model. Alternatively, an instance of `javax.swing.Timer` is slightly easier to `stop()` and `start()`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824180/should-i-be-using-a-java-worker-thread-for-this-cpu-simulation-app/6827200#6827200). On the view side, `setVisible()` may work, depending on your design.

Comment: It's easier for me to design it if I can simply "roll back" to an earlier state.  I don't know if that's always going to be feasible in this multi-threaded, interdependent GUI universe, but it's where I'd like to start :-)  Of course, if performance there becomes an issue, that's a different story.

Comment: @Chap create only one JFrame, re-use that, don't create lots of JFrames on fly, is pretty possible that from here coming you performancies problems